# fatal: unknown index entry format after search and replace

Tags: sed, git

How can I execute this search and replace on Linux without getting an error?

```
$ git status
On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean

$ find . -not -path './.git' -type f -exec sed -i -e 's/old/new/g' -e 's/old2/new2/g' {} +
$ git status
fatal: unknown index entry format 0x74650000
```

The strings `old` and `new` are placeholders.

Comment: The `sed` as shown looks very suspicious (unless the `old` and `new` are placeholders). If you actually globally replace all `old` by  `new`, then every `old2` will *already* have changed to `new2`. And all bold, gold and folder will be bnew, gnew and fnewer. I suspect you have munged something important within git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-path` test of `find` matches the *entire* name. From `man find` (emphasis mine):

> -path pattern
>
> File name matches shell pattern pattern.  The metacharacters do
> not treat `/' or` .' specially; so, for example,
>
> ```
>     find . -path "./sr*sc"
> ```
>
> will  print  an entry for a directory called ./src/misc (if one
> exists).  **To ignore a whole directory tree, use  -prune  rather
> than  checking  every  file in the tree.  Note that the pattern
> match test applies to the whole file name, starting from one of
> the start points named on the command line**.  It would only make
> sense to use an absolute path name here if the  relevant  start
> point  is  also an absolute path.  This means that this command
> will never match anything:
>
> ```
>  find bar -path /foo/bar/myfile -print
> ```
>
> Find compares the -path argument with the  concatenation  of  a
> directory  name  and  the base name of the file it's examining.
> Since the concatenation will never end with a slash, -path  ar‐
> guments  ending in a slash will match nothing (except perhaps a
> start point specified on  the  command  line).   The  predicate
> -path  is also supported by HP-UX find and is part of the POSIX
> 2008 standard.

So your `-not -path './.git'` isn't actually excluding anything. For example, on one of my repositories:

```
$ find . -not -path './.git' -type f | grep -m5 git 
./.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG
./.git/logs/HEAD
./.git/logs/refs/heads/master
./.git/description
./.git/HEAD
```

You wanted to use something like this, which excludes files starting with `./git/` and followed by any (or no) character(s):

```
find . -not -path './.git/*' -type f
```

But even that isn't what you really want. You want to just skip the entire `./.git` sub-directory and that's what `-prune` is for as mentioned in the man page I quoted above:

```
find . -type f \( -path './.git/*' -o -print \)
```